# Oracle golden gate to BigQuery

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, google-bigquery, goldengate

Im trying to setting up the Golden gate to sync the data to BigQuery. When I start pushing the initial load, my extractor exported all the data and even from the replicat stats Im able to see the records are received but its not pushed to Bigquery.

### Extractor

```
GGSCI (bhuvi-oracle) 12> info extract load1

EXTRACT    LOAD1     Last Started 2020-05-07 16:52   Status STOPPED
Checkpoint Lag       Not Available
Log Read Checkpoint  Table HR.TEST
                     2020-05-07 16:52:41  Record 32768
Task                 SOURCEISTABLE
```

### Replicat stats

```
GGSCI (bhuvi-1) 1> stats bq

Sending STATS request to REPLICAT BQ ...
gg.handlerlist=bigquery

Start of Statistics at 2020-05-07 16:53:33.

Replicating from HR.TEST to bhuvi_orcl.test:

*** Total statistics since 2020-05-07 16:52:42 ***
        Total inserts                                  32768.00
        Total updates                                      0.00
        Total deletes                                      0.00
        Total discards                                     0.00
        Total operations                               32768.00
```

### Log file on BigData Golen Gate:

```
2020-05-07T16:59:04.895+0000  INFO    OGG-00987  Oracle GoldenGate Command Interpreter:  GGSCI command (root): start bq.
2020-05-07T16:59:04.904+0000  INFO    OGG-00963  Oracle GoldenGate Manager, mgr.prm:  Command received from GGSCI on host [10.18.0.61]:42130 (START REPLICAT BQ ).
2020-05-07T16:59:04.905+0000  INFO    OGG-00975  Oracle GoldenGate Manager, mgr.prm:  REPLICAT BQ starting.
2020-05-07T16:59:04.964+0000  INFO    OGG-00995  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  REPLICAT BQ starting.
2020-05-07T16:59:04.967+0000  INFO    OGG-03059  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  Operating system character set identified as UTF-8.
2020-05-07T16:59:04.967+0000  INFO    OGG-02695  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  ANSI SQL parameter syntax is used for parameter parsing.
2020-05-07T16:59:05.173+0000  INFO    OGG-15052  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  Using Java class path: .:ggjava/ggjava.jar:ggjava/resources/lib/optional/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar:ggjava/resources/lib/optional/log4j-core-2.9.1.jar:ggjava/resources/lib/optional/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.9.1.jar.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.243+0000  INFO    OGG-01815  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  Virtual Memory Facilities for: COM
                                  anon alloc: mmap(MAP_ANON)  anon free: munmap
                                  file alloc: mmap(MAP_SHARED)  file free: munmap
                                  target directories:
                                  /opt/ogg/dirtmp.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.243+0000  INFO    OGG-00996  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  REPLICAT BQ started.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.251+0000  INFO    OGG-02243  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  Opened trail file /opt/ogg/dirdat/oo000000 at 2020-05-07 16:59:10.249063.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.251+0000  INFO    OGG-03506  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  The source database character set, as determined from the trail file, is UTF-8.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.253+0000  INFO    OGG-06505  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  MAP resolved (entry HR.TEST): MAP "HR"."TEST", TARGET bhuvi_orcl.test.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.253+0000  INFO    OGG-02756  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  The definition for table HR.TEST is obtained from the trail file.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.253+0000  INFO    OGG-06511  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  Using following columns in default map by name: ID.
2020-05-07T16:59:10.253+0000  INFO    OGG-06510  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, bq.prm:  Using the following key columns for target table bhuvi_orcl.test: ID.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what's wrong in this, actually nothing wrong. The glitch here is the mapping.

I was mapped my table names in prm file like below.

`MAP HR.TEST, TARGET bqtest.TEST`

I was thinking in bqtest dataset, I can see the Test table, But its not true. Goldengate will convert your mapping as `bqtest_test`. This is the actual table name. So you can see that this table got created automatically.